# What does this Cordova registry warning mean in the github facebook login plugin documentation?

Tags: warnings, cordova-plugins, cordova-facebook

After navigating to the github documentation for facebook from intel xdk plugin management section the second most prominent thing you see on the page is this.

<< --- Cordova Registry Warning [iOS]

*Installing this plugin directly from Cordova Registry results in Xcode using a broken FacebookSDK.framework, this is because the current publish procedure to NPM breaks symlinks CB-6092. Please install the plugin through a locally cloned copy or re-add the FacebookSDK.framework to Xcode after installation.*

------------------------------------------ >>

The link the the github page is here

https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin.

Can someone explain what this really means? It's already terribly confusing to get the basic fb login up and running on my mobile app, this warning is confusing the process for me even more as it assumes I know more than I do. 
Can someone break this down in beginner terms? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

The FacebookSDK.framework will be delivered broken if you fetch it from [NPM](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/what-is-npm), because the publish procedure to NPM breaks [symlinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). I can't tell you more then that.

## Workaround

The [workaround](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workaround) is cloning the repository of the plugin 'phonegap-facebook-plugin' with [GIT](https://git-scm.com/) and adding the plugin to your PhoneGap/Cordova project.

Enter the following command in your CMD or Terminal to clone the repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin
```

Enter the following command in your CMD or Terminal to add the plugin to your PhoneGap/Cordova project:

```
cordova -d plugin add /path/to/cloned/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
```

## Solution

The developers of the plugin 'phonegap-facebook-plugin' have a [solution for cordova > 4.0.0](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/pull/1022/files) in the develop branche of the plugin's repository.

## More info for installing the plugin:

- [Android](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/platforms/android/README.md)
- [iOS](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/platforms/ios/README.md)